# Symfony2 andWhere not working - just leave empty

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I'm trying to build something based on options, and I use a QueryBuilder to make a request with JOIN and ORDER

Here's a simple example of code I could produce :

```
$query      = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.ville', 'v')
        ->andWhere('s.name = :name')->setParameter('name', 'test')
        ->orderBy('s.id');
```

This lead to an exception... "Expected Literal, got 'ORDER'" 'cause in the final request, the WHERE clause is empty...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a where ? andWhere mean you have many where in your query :).
(Take care I think you want the name of the 'ville', because of your leftJoin).

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.ville', 'v')
        //v.name ?
        ->where('s.name = :name')->setParameter('name', 'test')
        ->orderBy('s.id');
```

Comment: I think the first `andWhere` is smart enough to detect that there was no `where` before and acts just like `where`. You might be on the right track with `v.name` though. Wait a second.. isn't there a `from` statement missing?

Comment: `createQueryBuilder('s')` is the from statement in sf2 queryBuilder

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using `doctrine/orm` < 2.4. In previous versions you had to use `where()` before an `andWhere()`. In [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.5/reference/query-builder.html) from version `2.5` they say:

> // NOTE: ->andWhere() can be used directly, without any ->where() before

However, It's fixed in version `2.4.8` too, so you could use that version too.